# Ingress route pointing to the wrong service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s

I've setup k3s v1.20.4+k3s1 with Klipper Lb and nginx ingress 3.24.0 from the helm charts.
I'm following [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes) but I'm stumbling upon a very weird issue where my ingress hosts would point to the wrong service.

Here is my configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-routing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: echo1.stage.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: echo1
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: echo2.stage.example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: echo2
              port:
                number: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo1
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo1
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo1
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        args:
        - "-text=This is echo1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5678

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo2
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 5678
  selector:
    app: echo2
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo2
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo2
        image: hashicorp/http-echo
        args:
        - "-text=This is the new (echo2)"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5678
```

And my Cloudflare DNS records (no DNS proxy activated):

```
;; A Records
api.stage.example.com.  1   IN  A   162.15.166.240
echo1.stage.example.com.    1   IN  A   162.15.166.240
echo2.stage.example.com.    1   IN  A   162.15.166.240
```

But when I do a curl on echo1.stage.example.com multiple times, here is what I get:

```
$ curl echo1.stage.example.com
This is echo1
$ curl echo1.stage.example.com
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
$ curl echo1.stage.example.com
This is the new (echo2)
```

Sometimes I get a bad gateway, sometimes I get the `echo1.stage.example.com` domain pointing to the service assigned to `echo2.stage.example.com`. Is this because of the LB? Or a bad configuration on my end? Thanks!

EDIT: It's not coming from the LB, I just switched to metallb and I still get the same issue

Comment: your configuration files are completely fine. I checked them in my local kind cluster.

Comment: I think your dns can't be resolved properly thats why you are facing 502 bad gateway error.

Comment: @PulakKantiBhowmick okay for 502 but how can I explain the fact that the wrong service is being used sometimes? :( Do you get the same behavior on your side with your kind cluster?

Comment: It works fine in my local kind cluster. I don't find any issue there.

Comment: Can you please add full domain in your dns record?

Comment: `echo1.stage.productive.place` & `echo2.stage.productive.place` but I'm experimenting on the cluster that's why I didn't include it

Comment: ok so I was able to reduce the scope of possible issues, I removed all the configuration that I have & recreated a cluster from scratch with only those two services in there and the issue is gone so I must have an issue with my Kustomize configuration

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the issue. It was actually not related to the config I previously posted by to my `kustomization.yaml` config where I had:

```
commonLabels:
  app: myapp
```

Just removing that `commonLabels` solved the issue.